# Silverstripe 3.0 return dataobjects and page url's in one function

Tags: php, silverstripe, data-objects

I am using Silvertripe 3.0 and currently have a simple page setup that has a couple children pages. The children pages have data objects that contain images, I am trying to get both the images and the url of the children page to appear on the parent page. I have the following code in my template:

```
<% loop $Children %>
    <a href="$Link">$Title</a>
<% end_loop %>

<div id="whiskyMainGallery">

    <% control WhiskyGallery %>
        <div class="item">

            <a href="$WhiskyPageID">$Slide.SetRatioSize(220,178)</a>

        </div>

    <% end_control %>

</div>
```

Both of these controls work as expected, but I am try to combine them so I get the data object image from WhiskyGallery control as well as the URL so i can call something like the following in my template:

```
<% control JoinedStuff %>
    <a href="$ChildPageUrl">$DataObjectImage</a>
<% end_control%>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my whiskyPage class:

```
class WhiskyPage extends Page {

    public static $db = array(
        'ABV'       => 'Text',
        'Colour'    => 'Text',
        'Aroma'     => 'HTMLText',
        'Taste'     => 'HTMLText',
        'Finish'    => 'HTMLText'
    );

    public static $has_many = array(
        'TastingAwards' => 'TastingAward',
        'WhiskyImages'  => 'WhiskyImage'
    );

   public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $gridFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create(); 
        $gridFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldBulkEditingTools());
        $gridFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder'));   

        $gridfield = new GridField("TastingAwards", "Tasting Awards", $this->TastingAwards()->sort("SortOrder"), $gridFieldConfig);

        $gridFieldConfig2 = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create(); 
        $gridFieldConfig2->addComponent(new GridFieldBulkEditingTools());
        $gridFieldConfig2->addComponent(new GridFieldBulkImageUpload());   
        $gridFieldConfig2->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder'));  

        $gridfield2 = new GridField("WhiskyImages", "Whisky Images", $this->WhiskyImages()->sort("SortOrder"), $gridFieldConfig2);

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Tasting Notes', new TextField('ABV', 'ABV'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Tasting Notes', new TextField('Colour', 'Colour'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Tasting Notes', new HTMLEditorField('Aroma', 'Aroma'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Tasting Notes', new HTMLEditorField('Taste', 'Taste'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Tasting Notes', new HTMLEditorField('Finish', 'Finish'));

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Tasting Awards', $gridfield);
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.WhiskyImages', $gridfield2);

        return $fields;

    }

}
```

My WhiskyImage DataObject

```
class WhiskyImage extends DataObject {

    public static $db = array(  
      'SortOrder'   => 'Int',
      'Title'       => 'Varchar',
      'Featured'    => 'Boolean'
    );

    // One-to-one relationship with whisky page
    public static $has_one = array(
    'Slide'         => 'Image',
    'WhiskyPage'    => 'WhiskyPage'
    );

    // tidy up the CMS by not showing these fields
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main","WhiskyPageID");
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main","SortOrder");

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new CheckboxField('Featured', 'Featured'));

        return $fields;
    }

    // Tell the datagrid what fields to show in the table
    public static $summary_fields = array( 
       'ID'         => 'ID',
       'Title'      => 'Title',
       'Thumbnail'  => 'Thumbnail'
    );

    // this function creates the thumbnail for the summary fields to use
    public function getThumbnail() { 
        if ($Image = $this->Slide()->ID) { 
            return $this->Slide()->SetWidth(80); 
        } else {
            return '(Please upload an image)'; 
        }
    }

}
```

The WhiskyLandingPage has it's own class, but nothing interesting in it, except a custom function to return the Images

```
public function GetWhiskyGallery() {
    return WhiskyImage::get()->filter(array('Featured' => 1))->sort("SortOrder");
}
```

Hope that makes a bit more sense!

Comment: from what you explain the exact structure is unclear to me, could you please paste the php code of all relevant classes (Page, WiskeyGallery, ...)

Comment: Sorry for the vague explanation, I have updated with more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you should use `loop` instead of `control` in the templates

second, joining dataobjects and pages seems like a rather bad idea and you will probably run into problems.
why not just loop the pages and then loop the dataobjects?

like so:

```
<% loop $Children %>
    <a href="$Link">$Title</a>
    <ul>
       <% loop $WhiskyImages %>
           <a href="$Top.Link" title="link to the whisky page">Image: $Title</a>
           <a href="$WhiskyPage.Link">this link will also link to the wisky page</a>
           $Slide.SetRatioSize(220,178)
       <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
<% end_loop %>
```

// EDIT:

in your example where you just loop a list of all `WhiskyImage` objects, you can do this:

```
<div id="whiskyMainGallery">
    <% loop WhiskyGallery %>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="$WhiskyPage.Link">$Slide.SetRatioSize(220,178)</a>
        </div>
    <% end_loop %>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first example renders no images and I believe you have a typeo, <% loop $WhiskyImages %> should be <% if $WhiskyImages %> :)

Comment: Your second solution, was exactly what I was after. Thank you very much! Also, you may want to change end_control in the second example to end_loop.

Comment: no, it was suppose to be loop, but the end_if was suppose to be loop... stupid copy paste misstakes